# grep search with alternation

Tags: linux, unix, search, grep

`grep "^\[bugID[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\]"` is for first line. How can I `grep` for `bugID` **or** `TICKET-`

```
[bugID12345] fix for performance issue

[TICKET-12345] fix for memory leak issue

[bugID23244] fix for performance issue

[TICKET-54678] fix for memory leak issue
```

Comment: please, rephrase your question and use 4 whitespaces to indent code; your post is hard even to edit

Comment: As @rubens said, please rephrase and actually ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep` supports alternation with `|` also `[` needs escaping:

```
egrep "^\[(bugID|TICKET-)[[:digit:]]{1,}\]" file
[bugID12345] fix for performance issue
[TICKET-12345] fix for memory leak issue
[bugID23244] fix for performance issue
[TICKET-54678] fix for memory leak issue
```

If you don't want the whole line then use the `-o` option:

```
egrep -o "^\[(bugID|TICKET-)[[:digit:]]{1,}\]" file
[bugID12345]
[TICKET-12345]
[bugID23244]
[TICKET-54678]
```